# Why do exceptions in asynchronous C# socket code terminate my program without stack trace?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have a C# Windows UI program, with a `Window1 : Window` in whose constructor I start an asynchronous socket server that `while (true) { /* BeginAccept */ }` and streams data to any client that connects using `BeginSend` and `EndSend`.

If one of the clients is forcibly disconnected `Socket.EndSend` throws an exception (a bit surprisingly `ObjectDisposedException` instead of `SocketException`, but whatever).

That exception **terminates my whole program** (closing the window) but does not print a stack trace!

Instead, I only get an innocent

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
```

message in the Ouput panel.

If exceptions are *silenced* like this but still crash my program without stack trace, how am I supposed to find where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what version of .NET you are using.  But, that's generally what's documented will happen.

If you don't want that to happen, use top-level exception handlers in your thread entry points and "swallow" the exception--logging it or whatever else you want to do before exiting the thread.

In terms of methods like `BeginSend`, the method given to `BeginSend` (or `BeginAccept` for that matter) is effectively the thread entry-point.  e.g.

```
listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAccept, null);
//...

private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try {
        var tcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        //...
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Dump(ex);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I first thought this fixed it, but it doesn't: Even if I catch all exceptions around both `BeginSend` and `EndSend`, killing a client still sometimes kills my program (this time actually with a `SocketException`) :/

Comment: Ah, of course: I had an old `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` around that was not secured in a `try` block. Also, running in `Release` mode actually reveiled the stack trace to the exception that stopped my program.

Comment: @nh2 I was just about to mention that any other Begin/Ends would need to have the same try/catch...